# php regex for data scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping

given the following link:

```
http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/floc.php/certificati/index/codice_ente/1030491450/cod/4/anno/2012/md/0/cod_modello/CCOU/tipo_modello/U/cod_quadro/01
```

how am I supposed to scrpae the value of **Popolazione residente (ab.)**?

I have tried with some prehistorical code of mine, but it's terribly slow and many datas get unprocessed.
For example if I process 300 links, about 180/200 are not processed.

Any clue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is verry difficult due to the fact that the first table doesn`t have a unique identifier(nor id nor class).
**THIS WILL NOT WORK FOR EVERY PAGE!!!**, it's more of an option at this point.
You would have to change the implementation depending on other page content with a case depending on the link I suppose....
I would use https://github.com/fabpot/goutte and implement something like this:

```
class MyController ...
public function __construct()
{
    $this->count = 0; //no iteration
    $this->scraped = array();
}
.....
public function scrape($url)
{
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
    $crawler->filter('table > tbody >tr >td')->each(function ($node) { //find all td`s
        $this->count++;//increment
        if($this->count == 1)
        {//if first td with the text you want...
            $this->scraped[] = $node->text();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'll have a look to your code. I was using another class that crwals the cose. Actually the tables have all the same class and so do the td's. Oh...maybe you mean that there's no identification for the specific cell or row. By the way I was making a check on the whole set of words "Popolazione residente (ab.)". It works but it's waaaay tooo slow!

Comment: yes there is no idebtification or no pattern to identify that specific td...a table id would have helped at least or a dynamic class (each td having something like class1 for firsr row....class2 second...) any pattern...it must involve a pattern for performance...